# Runtime tail-call optimization in recursive function templates

Tags: c++, templates, tail-call-optimization

Several libraries generate control flow structures from templates, e.g. table dispatch for "safe `switch`" or visitor patterns.

Has anyone measured the stack memory usage of such structures or published anything about their interaction with, or general feasibility of, tail call optimization?

I'm considering a runtime recursive strategy, i.e. generating a loop from a template. If it  cannot rely on tail call optimization it will inevitably overflow the stack.